# Sharepoint PeopleEditor: How to find out what kind of user/group is returned?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a PeopleEditor:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="peopleEdit" ... SelectionSet="User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup" />
```

It works flawlessly on the page, i.e. I can select AD users, Sharepoint groups and anything I would like.

The problem is that I can't find a property on the PeopleEditor of **what kind of user/group is returned**. Let's take the following example:

```
//User: John Doe - mycompany\jondoe  is at position 0
//Sharepoint group: "All Site Users" is at position 1

PickerEntity pickerEntity1 = (PickerEntity).peopleEdit.ResolvedEntities[1];
// pickerEntity1.Key = "All Site Users"
// pickerEntity1.Claim = null
// pickerEntity1.DisplayText = "All Site Users"
PickerEntity pickerEntity0 = (PickerEntity).peopleEdit.ResolvedEntities[0];
// pickerEntity1.Key = "mycompany\jondoe"
// pickerEntity1.Claim = null
// pickerEntity1.DisplayText = "Doe, John"
```

I can do some "hackish" things like trying to cast the returned string [sic] value as a User or as a Group and do some kind of Exception based program flow (*if user exists do this, else if group exist etc.*), but I wouldn't consider that clean code.

**Is there a better method of choosing people/groups in Sharepoint or a better method to work with the PeopleEditor?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `PrincipalType` value from the `EntityData` hashtable:

```
string principalType = pickerEntity1.EntityData["PrincipalType"].ToString();
```

I don't remember all possible values but `User` and `SharePointGroup` are definitely among them.

---

*[moontear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266453/moontear)'s comment:*

To list all information this entity has, the `EntityDataElements` array is helpful. For `SPGroup` this contains `SPGroupID`, `AccountName`, `PrincipalType`.

---

*[Janis Veinbergs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50173/janis-veinbergs)'s comment:*

It could be that it contains values from `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPrincipalType` enum but i haven't tested it.

Here you go:

```
[Flags]
public enum SPPrincipalType
{
    None = , 
    User = 1,
    DistributionList = 2,
    SecurityGroup = 4,
    SharePointGroup = 8,
    All = SharePointGroup | SecurityGroup | DistributionList | User, 
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, perfect! To list all information this entity has, the `.EntityDataElements` array is helpful. For a SPGroup this contains "SPGroupID", "AccountName", "PrincipalType"

Comment: It could be that it contains values from `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPrincipalType` enum. But i haven't tested it. Here you go: 
`[Flags]
  public enum SPPrincipalType
  {
    None = ,
    User = 1,
    DistributionList = 2,
    SecurityGroup = 4,
    SharePointGroup = 8,
    All = SharePointGroup | SecurityGroup | DistributionList | User,
  }`

Comment: @moontear I added your comment to the answer because it contains valuable information and this way it is more readable.

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs I added your comment to the answer because it contains valuable information and this way it is more readable.