# Check whether an account is User or Group - Sharepoint People Picker

Tags: sharepoint, peoplepicker

I'm working in a sharepoint application. i am using sharepoint PeoplePicker to get ADUser and SPGroup. How can i differentiate the output from the peoplepicker is an SharepointUser or SharepointGroup

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharepoint PeopleEditor: How to find out what kind of user/group is returned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181056/sharepoint-peopleeditor-how-to-find-out-what-kind-of-user-group-is-returned)

Answer (score 1):

sharepoint site user always have some domain. but for sharepoint site group we dont mention domain of system.like user is"domain-name\abc" while group is "Site Owner, Site Member , site viewer". we add users to sharepoint with domain-name.

Comment: ok, i will assume if the account has '\' as user or group. Is it correct way.

Comment: yeah account always come in format "domain\user".so u can easily diffrentiate between site user and site groups by this '\' format. hope this help

Comment: I found an answer in Stackoverflow itself, (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PickerEntity)pplEditorMembers.Entities[0].EntityData["PrincipalType"] it will return User/SharepontGroup.